# Linux - Raspberry Pi - Keep portable dvd drive awake/alive

Tags: linux, command-line, raspberry-pi, dvd, raspbian

I am trying to use my portable dvd drive with my raspberry pi and I have gotten the drive to activate using mount

"sudo mount /dev/sr0 /media/cdrom_a"

and copy some of the files off of it, but about 10 minutes into the copying the drive just stops(mid-copy) and shuts down

I can try to mount it again, but "sr0" is no longer in the "/dev/" directory, so I am looking for the linux equivalent of a "stay alive" or "stay awake" command for the dvd drive.

Comment: I bet it's due to the crappy power provision of the Pi's usb ports. Maybe a powered hub will help, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

After trying to execute another copy(in various ways) on an ubuntu system I got the same error again. I used a command ddrescue or gddrescue(as called in apt) used to backup information from less than healthy sources, so there is more care in the retrieval process(including the drive) and this was able to execute the copy while keeping the drive awake/alive.